# Why is my array being flipped?

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation, flip

```
            public const T = true;
            public static bool[,] MassMediumHorizontal = new bool[,]
            { 
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T},
            {T,T,T,T,T,T}
            };
```

As you all can see, this array has a width of 6 and a height of 12.

When I compile it, the width and height is flipped.

If I place a break point while debugging (visual studio feature) then hover over the variable's name, it tells me the size of the array, and it says 12x6 (width x height).

---

Of course, If I want to get the opposite of this, then I would just make the original array 12x6 and end up with 6x12 after compiling.

But why does this happen in the first place? (I don't rotate it what so ever after compiling)

Comment: Um,I think you are reading it wrong. It's `height * width` or `row * column`, not `width * height` or `column * row`

Comment: If you think this is confusing, you haven't seen anything yet. This will blow your mind: http://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking about arrays as width and height is confusing the matter. The measurements start from the outer-most dimension.

Your outer dimension is 12, and the inner is 6. Hence 12 x 6. It's just the way it works.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clarifying it. It just seemed weird that the height and width are flipped. I guess I'll make all the changes to my arrays accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @Davud: It is not clear to me why you believe anything has been flipped. In C#, whether a two-d array is rectangular or ragged, the left index selects the row and the right index selects the column. Your belief that the left index is the column and the right index is the row is simply incorrect. I am interested to know where your incorrect belief comes from. Why did you have this incorrect belief that the left index selects the column?

Comment: @EricLippert Probably based on the visual layout of the 2D array when you initialize it the way he's doing it. I know I've made the same mistake multiple times myself (which means I always remember it now).

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken: But that's an explanation that doesn't explain anything. I look at that layout and I think "12 rows with 6 columns".  Why should I then conclude that the left hand index selects the column? The OP's confusion is that they think that the left index is the column, but why is that the "more natural" way to think about it?

Comment: @EricLippert For me it's been based not so much on a rational idea of what is more natural so much as a vain hope that the visual layout on the page would match up with what happened when I iterated over it in the most obvious way. (That is, `for i in 0..n: for j in 0..n: print(array[i][j])`, with line breaks after each inner loop.) I recall getting quite far into a chess GUI before realizing that the board was 90 degrees off. I agree that it doesn't explain anything, and would also point out that when I realized it I immediately saw why it was wrong and fixed it, rather than running to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't really have a concept of 'width' and 'height', the dimensions are arbitrary.

It just so happens that the length of the array in first dimension is 12 and the length of the array in the second dimension is 6, so it's a 12x6 array. The fact that you and I conventionally think of the first dimension as 'width' and the second as 'height' is not relevant to the compiler.